# after page load get sound rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio

I did a rails application and when the user lands on a certain page it reproduces a sound. Everything works good on my PC but if I open it on an iPhone, I didn't get the sound.

This is what I have on the landing page

```
<%= audio_tag "cat.mp3", class: "audio-play" %>
```

and this is what I have in the application.js

```
$(".audio-play").get(0).play()
```

anybody knows why it is not working on the phone?

Comment: have you tried other phones or try your phone to play other music/sounds because it may be settings on your phone

Comment: I tried different phones but nothing

Comment: is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: your PC means on development mode? and trying it on phone means on production?

Comment: my rails app is on Heroku. if i land on the page on my pc I get the sound. if I land on the page on a phone I don't get the sound. if I land on the page on a pc in inspect page to see how it works on a tablet or a phone I get the sound

Comment: I would host the audio file on external location  and also don't use ruby tag but simple html. Try something like this <a src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/17041299'></a>

Comment: i cant get it work. Now i tried with this <audio class="audio-play" id="yes-audio" controls preload="none"> 
   <source src="http://wav-sounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Movie-01.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
and the same it works with pc but not with the phone